# How do I do Linearization at a point that lies on a curve?

Tags: calculus, linear-approximation

I keep applying the formula to the info given but I keep getting lost/weird answers. Can someone please help me?

I know $L(x)=f(a)+f'(a)(x-a)$

## question

Y(x) satisfies $x^2y^2 + xy = 6$. Point (x,y) lies on this curve. Find the linearization of y(x) at x=1.

I tried doing the derivative of the function and plugging in but idk how to get the answer.

I got $y'=2xy^2+2y\frac{dy}{dx}x^2+y+x\frac{dy}{dx}=0$

Please help me. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know about implicit differentiation? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function#Implicit_differentiation

Comment: Yeah I'm not great at it though. I updated with what I calculated the derivative to be

Answer (score 1):

So taking the derivative,
$$\begin{split}
0 &= 2xy^2 + 2x^2yy'+xy'+y \\
0 &= y+ 2xy^2 + \left(2x^2y+x\right)y' \\
y' &= -\frac{y+ 2xy^2}{2x^2y+x} = -\frac{y \left(1+ 2xy\right)}
                                        {x\left(2xy+1\right)}
    = -y/x \\
\end{split}
$$
So now you can apply linearization:
$$
L(a) = y(a) + (x-a) y'(a)
     = y(a) - (x-a) y(a)/a
$$
and you should be able to take it from here

Comment: OK I think I followed that. So would I just plugin 1 for x? I don't understand what x and a are. Like (x-a) is the difference, and one of them is 1 lol but idk which.

Comment: @Cozen $a=1$, so when all is done you get a *linear* function of $x$, hence the name *linearization*.